# Rustyline CLI prompt displaying the strange sequence ( looks like ANSI escape sequence) up on holding down the 'Enter" key on SSH session

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, rust-cargo

SSH to an Ubuntu Linux environment with rustyline based CLI , sometimes strange characters show up at beginning of CLI prompt (;1R), pressing/holding down the "Enter" key on CLI prompt sometimes shows " ^[[44;1R " or  " ^[[24;1R " .  What are these special characters and How to fix this?

```
abcd-> ;1R (Beginning of CLI prompt)
abcd->
abcd->
abcd->
^[[44;1R  (pressing/holding the "Enter" key on keyboard)
abcd->
```

Comment: most probably your command line doesn't support some character or something like that.